# Temperature relationships (ºC, ºF and ºK)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, ratio

In a curious exercise I found, I know that the relationship between ºC and ºF can be given by:
$$F=\frac95C+32$$

I also know that the relationship between ºC and ºK can be given by:
$$C=K-273,15$$

I'm curious, how can I get the relationship between ºK and ºF?

I've tried replacing, but just got stuck in a endless loop.

The choices I have are:

A) $K=\frac{9F-288}{5}+273,15$

B) $\frac{K-273.15}{9}= \frac{F-32}{5}$

C) $\frac{F-32}{9} = \frac{K-273.15}{5}$

D) $\frac{5F-150}{9}-273.15$

Comment: Just replace $C$ with what it is: $F = \frac 9 5 (K - 273.15) + 32$

Comment: Added some details to the original question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solve each of the two equations for $C$, then set the resulting expressions equal to each other, eliminating $C$:
$$ C=\frac59(F-32)$$
$$C=K-273.15$$
therefore
$$\frac59(F-32) = K-273.15$$
From this you can see that answer (C) is correct.

Answer (score 3):

\begin{align*}
F &=\frac95 \underbrace{C}_{ K-273.15}+32 \\
&=\frac95 \left( K-273.15 \right) + 32
\end{align*}

Now which of $A, B, C, D$ is equivalent to this?

Comment: I can't point the finger exactly. But C seems to sand out, but I can't point why. or how did 9 and 5 got to where they got.

Comment: @ddrjm check!  Try solving c) for $F$, and see if it looks the same.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Ok, I did try to solve it, but the closest I managed was the expression in the answer without the $\frac95$ which I'm not sure it is the right answer.